# Search Users in Specific OU Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory, ou

I have different OU in my Active Directory for different users, I want to get all users of a specific OU using C#.

Currently I have this filter, but it returns all users from all OU

```
(&(objectClass=User)(objectCategory=Person))
```

Kindly help me in finding users of specific user using ldap

Answer (score 7):

You can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
// LDAP string to define your OU
string ou = "OU=Sales,DC=YourCompany,DC=com";

// set up a "PrincipalContext" for that OU
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "Yourcompany.com", ou))
{
    // define the "query-by-example" user (or group, or computer) for your search
    UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);

    // set whatever attributes you want to limit your search for, e.g. Name, etc.
    qbeUser.Surname = "Smith";

    // define a searcher for that context and that query-by-example 
    using (PrincipalSearcher searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser))
    {
        foreach (Principal p in searcher.FindAll())
        {
            // Convert the "generic" Principal to a UserPrincipal
            UserPrincipal user = p as UserPrincipal;

            if (user != null)
            {
                // do something with your found user....
            }
        }
    }
```

If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`. Or see the [MSDN documentation on the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx) namespace.

Of course, depending on your need, you might want to specify other properties on that "query-by-example" user principal you create:

- `DisplayName` (typically: first name + space + last name)
- `SAM Account Name` - your Windows/AD account name
- `User Principal Name` - your "username@yourcompany.com" style name

You can specify any of the properties on the `UserPrincipal` and use those as "query-by-example" for your `PrincipalSearcher`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
But I have to do this using ldap

Comment: @MuhammadTaqi: my response ***IS*** using LDAP!

Answer (score 4):

One option is to just set the organization unit (OU) when you create your `DirectoryEntry` object:

```
using (var entry = new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://OU={unit},OU=Accounts,DC={domain},DC=local"))
{
    // Setup your search within the directory
    var search = new DirectorySearcher(entry)
    {
        Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(memberOf=*))"
    };

    // Set the properties to be returned
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("SamAccountName");

    // Get the results
    var results = search.FindAll();

    // TODO Process the results as needed...
}
```